# SQL: Which index most reasonable for like-select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not very familiar with database indices. I have a table which I assume lacks a index to execute my query with acceptable speed.

My table looks like this:

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| word    | varchar(64)  | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| feature | varchar(128) | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| sig     | double       | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to select the `feature` row `ordered by sig` to get the `word`s

My query is

`SELECT word from MyTable where feature like 'walk#%' order by sig`

Which index would speed up the query the most? 
an index over feature+sig?
or
an index over word+feature+sig?

Can someone help me with that and give me an explanation why a certain key is better than another?

Thanks for the help

Comment: An index over feature and sig probably.

Comment: Index(es) can speed up `where` or/and `order by` nut not `select`. Try indexing `feature`, `sig` and their combinations. There's no better or worse indexing unless you provide some statistics to assess index selectivity

Comment: How many rows in your table?  20?  20 million?

Comment: About 200 million rows

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Not necessarily true.  If an index is used only for filtering, then the database must go out to the table to select the columns from the matching rows.  In many cases, if the index used to find the rows also contains those columns (called a covering index), there is less data to read and thus a query may perform better and/or scale better.  However, more columns in the index means more storage and slower updates, so it is a trade-off.  I wouldn't use a covering index for this unless it was the only way to get acceptable performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Btree-index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html) on `Feature`only:

```
 ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD INDEX myIndex USING BTREE (feature)
```

An index on col `word` will not help MySQL since it is just fetching the results at this Point. Same is true for the col `sig`.

B-Tree indices are best used for LIKE operations if the matcher does not start with a Wildcard (see [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html)). Standard is HASH-Indices which are best at equal/unequal column operations.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle (not sure about SQL Server)

I wouldn't see the need to index word as it is not included in the predicate list of the query. Therefore, definitely an index over **feature** would be recommended (with a caveat as per Benni's comment regarding leading wildcards). An index over sig may help in terms of the ordering. If the sig column is indexed then results will be returned in the order of the index and the additional **order by** in your query is not needed.